# PHP sending JSON list of dictionaries as POST data

Tags: php, api, rest

Hi i am trying to send a post request to an API, using PHP.

I have the following code. The API expects products to be a list of dictionaries like

```
[{"id":1, "name": "nyan"}, {"id": 2, "name": "cat"}]
```

I have the following code, which seems to be sending it correctly, but the API doesn't accept it, i am supposing that it is to do with the way PHP arrays are encodede, but can't really figure it out, any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
$data = array(
  key => "API_KEY",
  private_key => "PRIVATE_API_KEY",
  products => array(array(id => 73,
  name => "A nice t-shirt",
  description => "A nice t-shirt with a picture of a cat",
  price => 9.95,
  brand => "Cat t-shirts",
  category => 11,
  rating => 5))
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://api.clerk.io/v2/product/add');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/json');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: You can show api documentation, i fink you need one array not twoo `array(array(`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to **JSON String**,

So remove following line,

```
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

And update following line,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

> [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) generates URL-encoded query string from Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)));
```

Add Content length in your header

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    key => "API_KEY",
    private_key => "PRIVATE_API_KEY",
    products => array(
            array(id => 73,
                name => "A nice t-shirt",
                description => "A nice t-shirt with a picture of a cat",
                price => 9.95,
                brand => "Cat t-shirts",
                category => 11,
                rating => 5
            )
        )
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

echo '<br>'.$data_string;
```

you will get the products dictionaries from 'products' key. so you just have to pass 'products' key data to API.